# bash script pipe with several commands

Tags: bash, syntax

I have next simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s lastpipe
echo "hello" | { read test1; hashID=$(echo -n "$test1" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1) }
```

when I do run this script bash returns: **syntax error: unexpected end of file.** 
Where did I wrong?

Comment: Replace `}` with `;}`.

Comment: Notice that `hashID` won't contain anything if you populate it like this, see [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus , it helped

Comment: you should use shellcheck.net, it tells you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as @Cyrus said, it works

```
echo "hello" | { read test1; hashID=$(echo -n "$test1" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1); }
```

Thanks @Cyrus